# php syntax i am having an error with binding parameters and the SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am having a composite keys, which are the FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and LastSchoolAttended which are the basis of the school and it needs to be limited to 1. But, I am having an error at the moment with the $stmt = $conn-> prepare ($SELECT) which is I think, I made a wrong syntax with the $SELECT. I am just new to php. As you can see, I am having a Logical AND and I don't even sure if I am doing it right.

```
$SELECT = "SELECT
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    LastSchoolAttended
From information
Where FirstName = ? And MiddleName = ? And LastName = ? And LastSchoolAttended = ?
Limit 1";
$INSERT = "INSERT Into information (
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    HomeAddress,
    ContactNumber,
    LastSchoolAttended
) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $LastSchoolAttended);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $LastSchoolAttended);
$stmt->store_result();
$rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($rnum == 0) {
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssisis", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $Age, $HomeAddress, $ContactNumber, $LastSchoolAttended);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: *But, I am having an error with binding parameter* could you add what the problem is?  If any error message, this may be helpful.

Comment: _having an error..._ What error? - WHY did you delete the code from your question?

Comment: i am sorry i am just new to this, i am having an error with binding parameter. i am using a composite keys, which are the basis and needed to limit to 1. @B001ᛦ

Comment: @NigelRen how can i send you a message?

Comment: If you have any more details, add them to the question so anyone can help you.

Comment: I made an edit right now. I am having an error with the $SELECT. I am not even sure if my syntax is right. I am using a composite keys, and I want it to limit it to 1 to avoid repeating. @NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to debug your code.

There you can get detailed error report

```
<?php
$SELECT = "SELECT
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    LastSchoolAttended
From information
Where FirstName = ? And MiddleName = ? And LastName = ? And LastSchoolAttended = ?
Limit 1";
$INSERT = "INSERT Into information (
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    HomeAddress,
    ContactNumber,
    LastSchoolAttended
) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT)) {
    if ($stmt->bind_param("ssss", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $LastSchoolAttended)) {
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            if ($stmt->bind_result($FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $LastSchoolAttended)) {
                $stmt->store_result();
                $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
                if ($rnum > 0) {
                    $stmt->close();
                    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT)) {
                        if ($stmt->bind_param("sssisis", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $Age, $HomeAddress, $ContactNumber, $LastSchoolAttended)) {
                            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                                echo 'Successfully Executed';
                            } else {
                                echo 'Error 1: ' . $stmt->error;
                                die();
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo 'Error 2: ' . $stmt->error;
                            die();
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'Error 3: ' . $stmt->error;
                        die();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Error 3.5: There is no entries in the `information` table';
                    die();
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Error 4: ' . $stmt->error;
                die();
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Error 5: ' . $stmt->error;
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error 6: ' . $stmt->error;
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error 7: ' . $conn->error;
    die();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give me an error now and lead me to another page but it does not recorded on my database. I

Comment: I got an error and it says
Error 1: Column 'FirstName' cannot be null. What does this mean? I made an input in the First Name.

Comment: I have changed the answer again, you can try again